# Is it possible to have pair of IPs in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have so many HA machines that one of them is primary and the other is standby.  I have this playbook that copies a config file from primary and then from standby on local machine then use those files as input for a python script:

```
- hosts: primary
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: copy the config of primary to local
    fetch:
      src: /data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl
      dest: /AnsibleDir/primary
      flat: yes
- hosts: standby
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: copy the config of standby to local
    fetch:
      src: /data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl
      dest: /AnsibleDir/standby
      flat: yes
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: run python script
    shell: /AnsibleDir/driver.py
    register: myshell_output
  - name: copy the output to a local file
    copy:
      content: "{{ myshell_output.stdout }}"
      dest: "/AnsibleDir/output.{{ host }}"
```

and I use this command:
`ansible-playbook -i /Ansible/hostfile /Ansible/python.yml --extra-vars "host=test1"`

in `hostfile` I have this configuration:

```
[primary]
192.168.107.69
[standby]
192.168.107.70
```

I think that I should edit this file every time I want to run my playbook. so is it possible to have so many pairs of IPs?
for example something like this:

```
primary:1.1.1.1,standby:1.1.1.2
primary:1.1.1.3,standby:1.1.1.4
primary:1.1.1.5,standby:1.1.1.6
```

or can I assign each pair the variable I want instead of writing it in my command every time? like:

```
primary:1.1.1.1,standby:1.1.1.2,host:test1
primary:1.1.1.3,standby:1.1.1.4,host:test2
```

I searched a lot but I could't find anything and I'm new to ansible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would it be possible to describe the use-case? For example "Make equivalent changes to the configuration files of primary and standby". Then show the code you have and describe potential problems.

Comment: @VladimirBotka  actually i need to find the differences of configuration files in 2 machines. they need to be the same. in python script it will find the differences and fix them. so i need to have both configuration on my local then run the python script for them. my problem is that there are hundreds of HA machines and i needed a dynamic inventory. the python script generates a report. i needed this report with a unique name for each pair.

Comment: How should "the python script generated report" look like?

Comment: @VladimirBotka  a unique name that refer to pair. for example the 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2 report is like output.accounting. or 1.1.1.3 and 1.1.1.4 is like output.portal.

Comment: Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @VladimirBotka thank you for sharing this link. i'll try to observe it in my questions. and your answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q: *Is it possible to have a pair of IPs in Ansible?*

A: Yes. It is possible. For example, it might be useful to create groups in the inventory with all pieces of information.

```
[primary]
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.5

[standby]
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.6

[ha]
1.1.1.1 stdby=1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3 stdby=1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5 stdby=1.1.1.6
```

It's possible to simplify the fetching of the configuration.

```
- hosts: primary, standby
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: copy the config to local
    fetch:
      src: /data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl
      dest: /AnsibleDir/conf
```

Without `flat: yes` the configuration files will be stored in

```
/AnsibleDir/conf/{{ inventory_hostname }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl
```

Then it's possible to reference the configuration files by the inventory hostname. For example `groups['primary']` (`secondary` the same way). Take a look at `myshell_output` and select the data for `content` and `dest` from the `items`

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - name: loop primary config
    command: "/AnsibleDir/driver.py
              /AnsibleDir/conf/{{ item }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl"
    register: myshell_output
    loop: "{{ groups['primary'] }}"
  - name: copy the output to a local file
    copy:
      content: "{{ <SELECT-FROM-ITEM> }}"
      dest: "/AnsibleDir/output.{{ <SELECT-FROM-ITEM> }}"
    loop: "{{ myshell_output.results }}"
```

To reference primary/standby pairs use group `ha`. For example the play below changes the configuration both at primary and standby for all hosts in `ha`.

```
- hosts: ha
  tasks:
    - name: Change configuration at primary
      lineinfile:
        path: /AnsibleDir/conf/{{ inventory_hostname }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_dd
        regexp: <ADD-REGEXP>
        line: <ADD-LINE>
    - name: Change configuration at standby
      lineinfile:
        path: /AnsibleDir/conf/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].stdby }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_dd
        regexp: <ADD-REGEXP>
        line: <ADD-LINE>
```

> Q: *I need to find the differences of configuration files in 2 machines. they need to be the same. In python script, it will find the differences and fix them. So I need to have both configurations on my local then run the python script for them.*

A: Fix the configuration files in 2 machines

```
- hosts: ha
  tasks:
    - name: Fix primary and standby config
      command: "/AnsibleDir/driver.py
                /AnsibleDir/conf/{{ inventory_hostname }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl
                /AnsibleDir/conf/{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].stdby }}/data1/cronjobs/gen_ddl"
```

Comment: would you please give an example about this `ha`? how i can specify each on in tasks? where to use `stdby`?

Comment: Sure. I've updated the answer.